# What is wrong in this C code?

Tags: c, output

Here is code I was trying to compile

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int n;
   printf("Enter the value for the nuber to be tested\n");
   scanf("%d", &n);
   if(n <=10 && >= 1)
       printf("n is between 1 to 10\n");
   return 0;
}
```

So when I compile it it shows an error at the line   `if(n <=10 && >= 1)`

Comment: I can see you were new when you wrote this, so I'll go ahead and just post the comment here; please don't update the code in your question to reflect what's been posted in the answers (*especially* if the problem is solved). It makes the answers look silly, and in the event anyone has a similar issue and stumbles on this question, they can't use this to help them anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fix your [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

`scanf("%d", &n);`

And to check if `n` lies in range [1,10]

You should be using

```
if (n <= 10  && n >= 1) {
//Your Code
}
```

Comment: i changed my code as you suggested now it shows an error on  if(n <=10 && >= 1)

Comment: You made a typo which is not in the answer. Please read answers carefully!

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitchwhat does that mean i don't get can you point it out for me

Comment: [P0W](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1870232/p0w) wrote rightly `if (n <= 10 && n >= 1)` but you commented `if(n <=10 && >= 1)` which is *not* what P0W have written. Please read *carefully* the answers before complaining about them.

Comment: aha hahaha sorry i am a rookee and i think i need an eye chekup too thanks

Answer (score 1):

Enable all warnings and debug info for your compiler, i.e. use `gcc -Wall -g`. Learn to use the debugger (`gdb` on Linux). You made two mistakes:

1. first, your call to `scanf` is wrong

   ```
   scanf("%d, &n");
   ```

   This is doubly wrong, and GCC would have warned you.

   - First and most importantly, with a `%d` in its format string, `scanf` requires an address of integer argument like `scanf("%d", &n);` and you have some [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (your program would often crash).
   - Then, `scanf` can fail. Check its result (the number of successfully scanned items):

     ```
     if (scanf("%d", &n) <= 0)
       { fprintf(stderr, "failure to read a number\n");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
     ```
2. Your test `if (n >= 1 <= 10)` is also wrong. It should be `if (n>=1 && n<=10)`. Notice that for `n==20` the `n>=1` test is true and could give 1 (the conversion of the `true` boolean to an integer), which is less than 10; your incorrect test is probably parsed as `if((n>=1) <= 10)` which does not do what you expect (since that test is successful when `n` is 20).

---

BTW [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) 4.8, when invoked as `gcc -Wall` is giving two warnings, one for each above mistake. A good way of working is to improve your code till no warnings are given by the compiler. Then use the debugger `gdb` for some testing.